# unable to insert image by binary using ajaxfileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-ajax

I trying to use ajaxfileupload to upload image (using binary) to my database (sql server 2008). I not sure if I did the behind code correctly. When i try to send report without or with uploading any picture some error popout. I have post the error below. Do help me take a look on what went wrong.
Thanks.

AJAXFileUpload

```
 <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
    ThrobberID="myThrobber"
    ContextKeys="fred"
    AllowedFileTypes="jpg"
    MaximumNumberOfFiles=1
    UploadedComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadedComplete"
    />
```

Behind code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MP
{
public partial class Report : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String fullname = (String)Session["fullname"];
        String contact = (String)Session["contact"];

        lblFullName.Text = fullname;
        lblContact.Text = contact;
        lblDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        Session["datetime"] = lblDateTime.Text;
    }

    protected void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String fullname = (String)Session["fullname"];
        String contact = (String)Session["contact"];
        String datetime = (String)Session["datetime"];
        String typeofcrime = ddlTOC.SelectedItem.Text;
        String location = txtLocation.Text;
        String detail = txtDetail.Text;
        String picture = (String)Session["picture"];

        if (picture.Equals(""))
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=project; Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Report (fullname, contact, typeofcrime, location, CRdatetime, citizenreport) values ('" + fullname + "','" + contact + "','" + typeofcrime + "','" + location.Trim() + "','" + datetime + "','" + detail.Trim() + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            lblMessage.Text = "Report Submitted.";

            conn.Close();

            txtDetail.Text = "";
            txtLocation.Text = "";
        }
        else if (!picture.Equals(""))
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=project; Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Report (fullname, contact, typeofcrime, location, CRdatetime, citizenreport, picture) values ('" + fullname + "','" + contact + "','" + typeofcrime + "','" + location.Trim() + "','" + datetime + "','" + detail.Trim() + "','" + picture + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            lblMessage.Text = "Report Submitted.";

            conn.Close();

            txtDetail.Text = "";
            txtLocation.Text = "";
        }
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDetail.Text = "";
        txtLocation.Text = "";
    }
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] image = e.GetContents();
        Session["picture"] = image;
    }
}
}
```

Error(when report without uploading picture)

[image: Pic]

Error(when i press upload)

[image: pic]

Comment: why you are converting Session["picture"] to String.

Comment: how do I get the binary at other method without using session to store it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(picture)` instead of `if (picture.Equals("")); Objetc.equals` is for comparing objects, see [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)

Comment: thanks, it work when without uploading image. any idea how to make the upload image part work?

Comment: why are you converting Session["picture"] to String. in btnReport_Click Event. on AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete Event. set the session to null, if there isnt any file, else assign the bytes to session variable. and also pass the byte[] array to the query to save the image in database. one more suggestion, to be good use viewstate to save the image, if you are just using this image on single page.

Comment: I still trying learn about it so i not sure if session able to store byte.